# how to merge different commit in git log history

Tags: git, commit, rebase

let's say we have commits 1->2->3->4->5
I thought the history might be too long, I want the log to merge 1, 2 and 3 into one, say, 1'->2->3->4->5
how can I do this, should I use rebase? it seems that I can't push to remote repo after rebase.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use interactive rebasing, and be sure not to do it after you have pushed any of the commits. Check this link: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits

Comment: I think it's more nuanced than simply "don't use rebase after you've pushed any of the commits."  I think it's quite fine if it's a private branch.  But @user1615903 is correct, if it's shared with others and others are expected to pull that branch regularly (e.g., master), then you don't want to rewrite history--which is what rebase does.

Answer (score 0):

First enter interactive rebase mode

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

(replace 5 with how many commits you want to squash)

Then follow the instructions from the git book Squashing commmits -part.

[From the git book:](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits)

> It’s also possible to take a series of commits and squash them down
>   into a single commit with the interactive rebasing tool. The script
>   puts helpful instructions in the rebase message:
>
> ```
> #
> # Commands:
> #  p, pick = use commit
> #  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
> #  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
> #
> # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
> # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
> #
> ```
>
> If, instead of "pick" or "edit", you specify "squash", Git applies
>   both that change and the change directly before it and makes you merge
>   the commit messages together. So, if you want to make a single commit
>   from these three commits, you make the script look like this:
>
> ```
> pick f7f3f6d changed my name a bit
> squash 310154e updated README formatting and added blame
> squash a5f4a0d added cat-file
> ```
>
> When you save and exit the editor, Git applies all three changes and
>   then puts you back into the editor to merge the three commit messages:
>
> ```
> # This is a combination of 3 commits.
> # The first commit's message is:
> changed my name a bit
>
> # This is the 2nd commit message:
>
> updated README formatting and added blame
>
> # This is the 3rd commit message:
>
> added cat-file
> ```
>
> When you save that, you have a single commit that introduces the
>   changes of all three previous commits.